# Are function pointers function objects in C++?

Tags: c++, function, c++11, type-traits, function-object

The C++ standard defines function objects as:

> A function object type is an object type that can be the type of the
>   postfix-expression in a function call. ([link](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/n4727.pdf#section.23.14))

First I was thinking that function objects were functors, but then I realized that for a function pointer `ptr` of type `P` (not a function, but a function pointer), `std::is_object_v<P>` is `true` and can be called with the `ptr(Args...)` syntax.

I am right that function pointers are considered as function objects by the standard? And if they are not what part of the definition is not satisfied by function pointers?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes, they are. The term "object" in C++ standard does not mean "object" in the OOP sense. An `int` is an object.

Comment: @Rodrigo: The C++ standard doesn't use the term "functor" (and thus doesn't give it a definition).  Most people would define a functor in a way that includes all function objects that aren't function pointers

Comment: @Ben Voigt which is kinda misleading because original meaning of term supposes a mapping from one set to another, e.g. implemented as a pure function in functional programming. IMHO term "functor" must die and we should use term "callable object"

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie While I agree that the term *functor* should be avoided, "callable objects", unfortunately, include function pointers too.

Answer (score 2):

Function pointer is what it sounds like: a pointer to function. As  itself it's a storage containing a pointer object, which returns a callable of function type.

If you take time and read first chapters of standard, you 'll understand that any variable declaration declares some type of storage that contains *objects*. Those can be objects of primitive types or classes. Essentially *in C++ anything that can be stored is object*.

By declaring function pointer you create storage that can store address of that function and operator()  can be used

Anther type of callable closure can be created by lambda expression. They are not function objects, each expression creates a unique callable object, but captureless lambdas can be used as one, e.g. to assign it to a function pointer, e.g.

`double (*square)(double)  = [](double a)->double { return a*a; };`

after this you can call it using expression like `square(3.6);`

For functions and lambda call operator `operator()` is supplied by language, by defining `operator()` for a class you create what people often call "functor", which is misnomer because actual functors in mathematics or such languages like Haskell *do not* store state. Result of lambda expression is a "functor" created by compiler, which stores states of captured objects.

Naming those objects callable might be a little misleading too, because as a concept in C++, a callable object is any object that can be used with INVOKE operation, which include pointers to data members even while no function calls happen.

it leaves only one option, if we can use function call with said object, it's a function object. It can be  function, lambda expression, function object, function pointer, member function pointer with specified class instance ( `obj.*memberptr` or `objptr->*memberptr`  - call of member function is very special) - they are function objects.

Comment: A *function pointer* is a pointer to a *function*, not a pointer to a *function object*.  Pointers to function objects are object pointers.  A function is not an object.  Declaring a function does not describe a function object.  Finally, you can't use `operator()` with a member function pointer, so that is not a function object.

Comment: @BenVoigt I stand corrected. and it should not be opan erator, but expression... In latter case expression to be used is quite strange as well

Answer (score 0):

The function pointer are function object, but they also have a funny quirk  coming from C era:

```
#include <iostream>

int foo(int a)
{
    std::cout << "Hello, " << a << " stars\n";
    return a;
}
    
int (*pr) (int) = foo;

int main()
{
    pr(0);
    (*pr)(1);
    (**pr)(2);
    (***pr)(3);
    return 0;
}
```

The postfix expression shall have function type or pointer to function type and function is contextually convertible to a function pointer whenever such conversion is required, so repeating dereference operators bounce type "to and fro", leaving it be a function pointer. Captureless lambda would do too:

```
// also can write `auto pr2 = ...`
int (*pr2) (int) = [](int a)->int { 
         std::cout << "Hello, lambda " << a <<  " stars\n"; return a; 
};

// in main()
(**pr2)(2);
```

Naturally, that code is ill-formed if pr is a generalized "functor"

```
int b = 2;
auto pr3 = [=]()->int { 
   std::cout << "Hello, general lambda " << b << std::endl; 
   return b; 
};

pr3();
//(*pr3)();  Ill-formed: not a pointer!
```